# usage of the Global Platform Secure channel functionality

Tags: javacard, globalplatform

Can the the GP Secure Channel functionality be used for communications other than the ones for applet personalization or applet management?

For instance, can it be the case that a financial transaction is secured (authentication, integrity or confidentiality) using the GP Secure Channel protocol?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Yes, it can! Blah blah blah!You need to call Global Platform API methods in your applet that needs secure channel functionality. Refer to GlobalPlatform Specification for that.

Comment: @Abraham The question is more if you can / should use the GP keyset for this. I don't see how you can use the GP secure channel without also using the keys of the security domain. (you could have removed the blah blah blah when you expanded your comment :P )

Comment: @MaartenBodewes Ah, I was thought that the questioner have access to the SD Keys. So I referred him/her to the GP API Specifications for `SecureChannel`, `GPSystem` classes and `processSecurity()`, `unwrap()`, `getSecureChannel`, etc methods. Am I wrong about the questioner's intention?

Comment: @Abraham You should never use "blah blah..." or anything like this... It is not insulting, but there is a good reason why there is this minimum length of comment restriction. You could have added more info than just "Yes, it can", couldn't you?

Comment: @Abraham I don't know about the user's intent, but in general you don't want to use the same keys for multiple entities or purposes. It could be that using the SD keys is fine, but it might also not be the case. engy, you're the only one that can clear that up.

Comment: Thanks, Maarten, Abraham for your discussion. My question was indeed if it is a (common) practice/whether it is reasonable to use GP scp for other purposes than applet loading and personalisation and not whether it is possible to do that.  I understand from Maarten's comments that the answer is no.  Yet, in principle it should be possible to use a scp  with a different set of static keys - one for communicating between the issuer and the ISD, another one for other purposes. Am I right?